# Restart ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

For testing and writing code I need to restart my GameViewContrller

```
GameViewController *controller = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

This method restart viewController but all stored in memory because of my actions / processes going on, as in the application memory increases with each not reboot.
    I think this is not the correct way, and would like to know how, overburden viewController entirely so with memory, delete all the process and start again.

**update**

```
- (IBAction)restartButtonPress {
  //  GameViewController *controller = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil];
  //  [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Let's say I have a game scene (the scene is described all in gameview controller) at the conclusion of her I have to restart because the data is written to a file, how do I implement it?

Comment: your want to restart your view??

Comment: yes, becouse all action in game i creat in my gameviewcontroller, but with other data

Answer (score 2):

Call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` that use for reload you view. alos you can use `[self viewDidLoad]` method but it is not good for us and also  we don't call viewDidLoad manually. so you can use `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: @user2037857-http://jomnius.blogspot.in/2010/05/how-to-reload-current-uiviewcontroller.html

Answer (score 0):

This only starts a new one. It doesn't reset the old one.

To delete the old one you need to call `[controller release]` to the old one.

Comment: Let's say I have a game scene (the scene is described all in gameview controller) at the conclusion of her I have to restart because the data is written to a file, how do I implement it?